Definition of "interval of continuity" for function defined on sets
At the beginning of Chapter 8 of Kubilius's Probabilistic Methods in the Theory of Numbers, the author defines $Q=Q(E)$ to be a completely additive nonnegative function defined for all Borel subsets $E$ of $\Bbb R^n$ (that is, some kind of measure defined on the Borel subsets of $\Bbb R^n$). The author then uses the terminology that $I$ can be an "interval of continuity" of the function $Q(E)$ (nothing more is said about what $I$ is).
What is the precise definition of "interval of continuity" in this context? Where can I find that definition?
(Kubilius is actually talking there about Borel subsets not containing the origin, but I'm pretty sure that's irrelevant to my question.)

We do see this definition ... a measure $Q$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is called continuous iff $Q({x}) = 0$ for all $x$.  Is that relevant?

It might be relevant, but I definitely don't yet know the answer to my question even with that.

In standard measure theory, a continuity set for a Borel measure $\mu$ is any set $A$ such that $\mu(\partial A)=0$. I would presume that a continuity interval for $Q$ is just any interval $I$ for which $Q({\inf I})=Q({\sup I})=0$...

These are apparently "intervals" in $\Bbb R^n$. But the general idea is promising! Could you suggest a reference I could consult?
